# MySQL date query changing now with string not work

Tags: mysql, date

i am success with this query 1:

```
select date_format(now()-INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

but why result different with Query 2:

```
select date_format('2016-02-26'-INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%Y-%m-%d')
```

how to replace now with string of date?

Comment: Try this `select date_format(STR_TO_DATE('2016-02-26', '%Y-%m-%d') - INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%Y-%m-%d')`

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert the string to Date in MySql.

Try this:

```
  select date_format(STR_TO_DATE('2016-02-26', '%Y-%m-%d') - INTERVAL 1 DAY,'%Y-%m-%d')
```